# Pass data row from mat-table when click to another component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8, angular7-router

I want to pass full row to other component for display this data, any body have a way to do it.

Html:

```
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getRecord(row)"></mat-row>
```

ts:

```
  //Get row data when the click
  getRecord(row){
      // Do somthing ..... //
  }
```

I will searched a lot, i can't find way.

Comment: `row` variable should have row data, try to print it to console `console.log(row);`

Comment: You're already passing the data to your ````getRecord()```` function from your ````mat-table```` so I think your question is mainly about how to pass the data to your other component. What is the relationship between your components?

Comment: Yes i want to pass the row to other component, the relation is sibling .

Comment: the data is strings and int and image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem this steps after click on the row:

1. Save the data in variable in the service file.
2. use navigate for routing.
3. get the data from the variable in the service file.

```
   public  getRecord(row : any){
    console.log(row);
     this.userservice.dataRow = row;
     this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
  }
```

Service file:

```
    //Temporarily stores row data from mat-table
    dataRow:any;
```

profile.ts:

```
    this.dataRow = this.userservice.dataRow;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more than one way to accomplish passing data between siblings, but the Angular way is to use a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

You can also pass data via events. Have the row click fire an event that the parent component receives and then passes on to the child table's sibling via a function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this link for parent with children

Comment: Yes I know - that's what I answered - I see you've solved it with a service as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks very much (: i will increase your rate